# How to modify run_at of running delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

At some point i have a job which has to be run, but it's pushed in queue to the workers

example -

```
run_at = (Date.today + 2.days) + 4.hours
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ReleaseSecurityMoneyJob.new(transaction_id), run_at: run_at)
```

After 36 hours i want to extend this `run_at` time to for next `48.hours`

How can i achieve this.?

Comment: Find this job in delayed_jobs table and update `run_at` column?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `gem 'delayed_job_recurring'` and setup your job to run periodically

```
  class ReleaseSecurityMoneyJob < Struct.new(:transaction_id)
      include Delayed::RecurringJob
      run_every 4.days
      timezone 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
      queue 'slow-jobs'
      def perform
        ..
      end
  end
```

Then create this job just as you did, and it will blissfully execute every 4 days.

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ReleaseSecurityMoneyJob.new(transaction_id))
```

Then at some point you want to be finished, merely call

```
ReleaseSecurityMoneyJob.unschedule
```

However, this will unschedule all jobs of that class.  I think there are some options to select the specific job based on transaction_id.  You'll have to experiment a bit.